# Use a C++/CLI dll in a .NET Core 2 application

Tags: c++-cli, .net-core-2.0

Is it possible to use a .NET C++/CLI DLL from a .NET Core 2 application on Windows?

I have a DLL built with `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`. From a .NET Core test app, I do:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("mycliassembly.dll");
```

And I receive this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly ... Format of the executable (.exe) or
>   library (.dll) is invalid.

So the obvious answer would be no. But.. is there a way, assuming we are talking about Windows only?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140014/c-cli-support-in-net-core , https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24444 (not strictly C++/CLI, but P/Invoke and wrappers usable). Also, just target .NET Framework via .NET Standard..?

Comment: It is a duplicate but I think this this question is phrased more simply and the answer about using <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework> might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Alright according to the linked question, the best answer is from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40239864/283467]:

"As far as I know there is no plan to support C++/CLI with .NET Core."

So the solution is don't use .NET Core. Instead, since it's Windows only, use:

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

Hopefully Microsoft will continue to support ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework.