# Is it possible to use dotnet core in C++/CLI project

Tags: .net-core, c++-cli

When I created an empty project in **MSVS 2017** for **C++/cli** in section ***TargetFrameworkVersion*** I found supporting for **.net framework** only.
Is it possible to use **.net core** in **C++/CLI** project instead of **.net framework**?

Comment: Sorry, already found answer in this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140014/c-cli-support-in-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++/CLI Support in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140014/c-cli-support-in-net-core)