# Is it possible to build a .Net Core C++/CLI application targeting Linux and Windows

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am trying to build an application having below 3 layers

1. C# Layer
2. C++/CLI Wrapper layer
3. C++ Layer

I have build C# and C++/CLI layers in .Net Core 3.1. 
But I am not able to publish this in Linux platform.

From the Microsoft press release for .Net Core 3.1, its saying like .Net core C++/CLI will support only for Windows.

Is there any other way that I can achieve platform independency  at C++/CLI layer?

or is there any other way that I can communicate with C++ Layer directly from C#?

I tried to use pInvoke methode. But it cannot transfer C# object to C++.

**Target to achieve** is that with the same source code it should able to build in Windows, Linux and Mac OS without using any third party services.

**Note: For a C# application build in .NetCore we can achieve this. Only thing we need to do is publish the project for different platform.**

Comment: Yes you can, by docker

Comment: Hi @mehdizahrane , docker is like a Linux container right? Without using any other third party services need to achieve this platform independency. The application should work in Linux, Windows and Mac with same source code.

Comment: PInvoke is your only option. `C++/CLI` can only be used in Windows. Can you post some code to show us what you're trying to do? What functions are you attempting to call from `C#` to `C++`

Comment: Hi @WBuck, there will be some classes with some functionality in C++ layer. I am creating the instance of C++ class and calling those functionality from C# via CLI layer

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140014/c-cli-support-in-net-core/58071675#58071675

Comment: @marsahllDTitch docker for windows is different than docker for linux. its a NO.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer C# objects to C++ trough `GCHandle`. You also have to transfer pointers to C# functions into unmanaged code (get them via `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`).

Then in your unmanaged code you can call that function and pass the object handle as one of the arguments.

An example of C# code

```
public static unsafe void Invoke(System.IntPtr instancePtr, int param)
{
    var instanceHandle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(instancePtr);
    var instance = ((ClassInstance) instanceHandle.Target);

    instance.method(param);
}
```

So you have to transfer a pointer to `Invoke` function and an IntPtr to GCHandle (`GCHandle.ToIntPtr`) into C++ code.