# Is it possible to call a shared library (.so) on linux platform from .NET core?

Tags: c#, .net, shared-libraries, cross-platform, .net-core

I understand that aim of the .NET core is for cross platform development, but I am looking for backward compatibility. If I have a linux library available (maybe, legacy) and I want its functions to be called from .NET core application for linux platform. Is it possible?

I am not talking about ASP.NET core, I need it for a desktop application.

Comment: .NET Core Itself uses lots of such libraries on Linux. Can you check its source code to see how to make PInvoke there?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202027/p-invoke-in-net-core-with-linux/38210267#38210267

Answer (score 1):

Yes: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/343

That being said, I'll admit to not having actually tried it yet. I *have* used this a far bit on Mono, for what it's worth, and it's definitely worth reading their documentation on this: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/ ... because .net core seems to take much the same approach (eg: leave off the file extension for the p-invoked library, so the system can take care of linking to the right version etc...)

Eg how bits of .net core itself do this:

```
const string LIBC = "libc";

[DllImport(LIBC, EntryPoint = "getenv")]
private static extern IntPtr getenv_core(string name);
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/79d44f202e4b6d000ca6c6885a24549a55db38f1/src/System.Console/src/Interop/Interop.manual.Unix.cs

Answer (score 1):

Look at SWIG.  It is a simple way to wrap a shared library and it generates all of the P/Invoke code for you as well as maps any header files (think structs) between your .so library and your C# code.  We created a simple cpp wrapper around the .so library that we wanted to use and then let SWIG do its magic.  We now have a C# library that can call from our .Net code (a simple console app) that invokes our linux library functions.  We have done this on a PI, on unix hosts running Ubuntu, CentOS, and Debian with great success. http://www.swig.org/