# DllImport("msvcrt.dll") not working when it runs on linux

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-core

I want to compare 2 bytes array using memcmp function using below code

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll",EntryPoint = "memcmp", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);
```

When I run my application on Windows it is working fine. But when I run it on Linux it giving below exception

> Unable to load shared library 'msvcrt.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libmsvcrt.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Below is the docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
COPY NuGet.Config ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "XXX.dll", "YYY.dll"]
```

Please let me know what should I use?

Comment: With all due respect, calling out to an external dll from a .net app in order to compare two byte arrays seems somewhat silly.

Comment: for performance i need to use this function.

Comment: Looks like it really wants to be [`Span<T>.SequenceCompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.sequencecompareto?view=netstandard-2.1#System_MemoryExtensions_SequenceCompareTo__1_System_Span___0__System_ReadOnlySpan___0__)

Comment: That name starting with "ms" is suspicious, looks like a Microsoft DLL so it is platform specific (windows only).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Tell that to the npm-community/javascript-'developers'

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Will try this, if it works or not

Comment: _"for performance i need to use this function."_ - No, you don't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Thanks. It works. Performance is same like memcmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever. Thanks for your help.
I used below code

```
 if (((ReadOnlySpan<byte>)slice).SequenceCompareTo((ReadOnlySpan<byte>)masterSlice) == 0)
                    isEqual = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just use a 'windows' DLL on Linux. Just because you have a .NET Core runtime on Linux doesn't mean you can use other libraries / executables from the other platform/OS.

You should find some other code that can compare two byte arrays or stick to windows as the underlying OS.

Take a look here: [Comparing two byte arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net)

Comment: I have used foor loop, sequence equal, structural equal and finally i choose memcmp which gives good performance as compared to all. Could someone tell how I can i use equivalent dll for linux. I think libc.so can be use but dont know how to implement it in code. Is it some thing to add in docker file?

Comment: @vaishalikhatri With the knowledge gained, I'd say you could compose a new SO question when stuck.

Comment: You can PInvoke the libc.so library. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118816/2265446